# how can I change the lines and font

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<-structure(list(Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("WT", "Drug"), class = "factor"), 
    Hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L), Condition = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-109L))
```

I am trying to make a plot using survival analysis

```
require(survcomp)
require(survival)

km.coxph.plot(formula.s = Surv(Hour, Condition) ~ Sample, data.s = df, mark.time = TRUE,
  x.label = 'Time (Hours)', y.label = 'Overall survival', main.title = '',
  leg.text = c('WT', 'Drug'),
  leg.pos = 'left', leg.bty = 'n', leg.inset = 0,
  .col = c('forestgreen', 'red3'),
  #xlim = c(0, 40),
  o.text = '',
  .lty = c(1,1), .lwd = c(1.75, 1.75),
  show.n.risk = TRUE, n.risk.step = 2, n.risk.cex = 0.8, verbose = FALSE)
```

Now I am wondering if someone could possibly know how to change the font of `show.n.risk`
or if I can change the lines to dash and basically change the figure in a more representative (e.g. bigger fonts)

Comment: From CRAN: "Package ‘survcomp’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

This package is now available from Bioconductor only, see <http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/survcomp.html>."  Unfortunately that link does not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

So, after tracking down a current version of survcomp and going through the rather boring process of updating every out-of-date BioC package I was able to run you code. Looking at the code for `km.coxph.plot` makes it immediately clear that this is a base plotting function. The linetypes are obviously set with the `.lty` argument, so this modification will give you dashed lines:

```
.lty = c(2,3),
```

It's not clear what font you want for the n-risk values. Generally font specifications are handled with arguments to `text` or `mtext`. The text for the label is hard coded to font=2 which gives the bolding effect. The numeric values are being displayed without any optional argument to allow font changes. It would not be very difficult to hack a new version that did allow fonts specification but I am loathe to do any further work without a clear specification of desired end results. You could do the modifications yourself, or you could mark my response as answered if you need me to carry forward.

Answer (score 0):

The **survcomp** package was removed from CRAN about 10 years ago because it did not conform to R's policies. For example, functions, including `km.coxph.plot`, that assign and remove objects from the user's global environment. While this function can save you some time, it can also be inflexible. For example,

You can easily change the lines to dash using the `.lty` argument:

```
.lty = c(1,2) # 2 = small dash, 3 = dot, 4 = dot-dash, 5 = long dash, etc.
```

You can increase or decrease the "No. at risk" label using the `n.risk.cex` argument:

```
n.risk.cex = 1.1
```

However, changing the font for individual text is doesn't seem to work here. The usual method is to assign a name to a font using the `WindowsFonts()` function. Another option is to use the **extrafont** package. ([link](https://github.com/wch/extrafont/))

```
windowsFonts(A = windowsFonts("Times New Roman"))

km.coxph.plot(formula.s = Surv(Hour, Condition) ~ Sample, ..., family="A")
```

But you'll notice that this changes only the y-label and y-axis tick labels. The x-axis and "No. at risk" labels are unchanged.

Using the **extrafont** package doesn't seem to solve this problem.

So this appears to be one of the pitfalls of using non-conventional user-contributed packages, unless I'm missing something about this package.

Some alternatives are to use one of the ggplot ally packages, such as **survminer**, but I found that the fonts for the "No. at risk" label did not change as requested. So that's an issue to be resolved.

The sure failsafe method is to stick with base R and run your model first and then use `plot` and add things manually.

```
sfit <- survfit(Surv(Hour, Condition) ~ Sample, data = df)
plot(sfit, ...)
```